# sql-server rank function cope with duplicates by some restriction

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table like follow:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        NAME VARCHAR(20),
        MOBILE VARCHAR(20),
        TIME INT
)

INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'A','1111111',10
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'B','222222',20
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'C','333333',60
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'D','4444444',70
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'A','1111111',100
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'B','222222',10

SELECT NAME,MOBILE,TIME,
        RANK() OVER (ORDER BY TIME asc) AS xRank
FROM 
( 
SELECT NAME ,MOBILE ,TIME
FROM @Table
) AS a
ORDER BY 1
```

I want the result like below.If two row have same `NAME` and `MOBILE`, only show one row with lower  time:

[sqlfiddle 1](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/29044/0)

```
NAME    MOBILE  TIME    XRANK
A   1111111 10  1
B   222222  10  1
C   333333  60  3
D   4444444 70  4
```

[sqlfiddle 2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/29042/0)

```
NAME MOBILE TIME   XRANK
A   1111111 10      1
B   1111111 10      2
B   222222  20      3
C   333333  60      4
D   4444444 70      5
```

Comment: Please note your expected example output does not match your stated requirement: "If two row have same NAME and MOBILE, only show one row with lower time"; see  your SQLFiddle match your question!

Comment: @Mitch Wheat At first, I write wrong row 'B 1111111', but I fix it before anwser changing.Then anwser changed.I don't know if I should change link back?

Comment: @Vignesh Kumar Yes,thank you for anwser my question, but how can I genetate the row number?

Comment: @Mithril I can't get to you. what you want

Comment: @Vignesh Kumar `RN` in each row is 1 in your answser ,how can I make it to increasing row-number?

Comment: @Mithril I have updated my answer to generate row number. Please check now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this

```
SELECT name, 
       mobile, 
       time, 
       rn, 
       Row_number() 
         OVER ( 
           ORDER BY name) AS XRANK 
FROM   (SELECT name, 
               mobile, 
               time, 
               Row_number() 
                 OVER( 
                   partition BY name, mobile 
                   ORDER BY name ASC) AS RN 
        FROM   @Table) AS T 
WHERE  rn = 1
```

## [Working Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/29065)

**Output**

```
NAME    MOBILE  TIME    XRANK
A   1111111 10  1
B   1111111 10  2
B   222222  20  3
C   333333  60  4
D   4444444 70  5
```

Comment: @MitchWheat You din't generate  rank like serial number

Answer (score 2):

```
;with cteRank
as
(
  SELECT 
     NAME, MOBILE, TIME,
     rn = row_number() OVER (partition by name, mobile ORDER BY TIME asc)
  FROM @Table
)
SELECT NAME, MOBILE, TIME
FROM cteRank
where rn = 1
ORDER BY 1
```

Output ("If two row have same NAME and MOBILE, only show one row with lower time"):

```
NAME MOBILE TIME
A   1111111 10
B   1111111 10
B   222222  20
C   333333  60
D   4444444 70
```

Comment: I have changed the sqlfiddle, this anwser work with http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/29042/0 .Thank you.

Comment: I suddenly find that every answer can not show row number(xrank)